# Anagram Recursion Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, anagram

This is the question that I tried to write a code for.

---

*Consider a recursive algorithm that takes two strings **s1** and **s2** as input and checks if these strings are the anagram of each other, hence if all the letters contained in the former appear in the latter the same number of times, and vice versa (i.e. **s2** is a permutation of **s1**).*

*Example:*

*if s1 = ”elevenplustwo” and s2 = ”twelveplusone” the output is true*

*if s1 = ”amina” and s2 = ”minia” the output is false*

**Hint:** *consider the first character c = s1(0) of s1 and the rest of r =s1.substring(1, s1.size) of s1. What are the conditions that s2 must (recursively) satisfy with respect to c and r?*

---

And this is the piece of code I wrote to solve this problem. The problem is that the code works perfectly when there is no repetition of characters in the strings. For example, it works just fine for *amin* and *mina*. However, when there is repetition, for example, *amina* and *maina*, then it does not work properly.

How can I solve this issue?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Q32019 extends App {
def anagram(s1:String, s2:String, indexAr:ArrayBuffer[Int]):ArrayBuffer[Int]={

  if(s1==""){
    return indexAr
  }
  else {
  val c=s1(0)
  val s=s1.substring(1,s1.length)
    val ss=s2
    var count=0
   for (i<-0 to s2.length-1) {
    if(s2(i)==c && !indexAr.contains(s2.indexOf(c))) {
      indexAr+=i
      }
    }

    anagram(s,s2,indexAr)
  }
indexAr
}
  var a="amin"
  var b="mina"
  var c=ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var d=anagram(a,b,c)
  println(d)
  var check=true
  var i=0
  while (i<a.length && check){
    if (d.contains(i) && a.length==b.length) check=true
    else check=false
    i+=1
  }
  if (check) println("yes they are anagram")
  else println("no, they are not anagram")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to sort both strings and just compare them:

```
def areAnagram(str1: String, str2: String): Boolean =
  str1.sorted == str2.sorted

println(areAnagram("amina", "anima")) // true
println(areAnagram("abc", "bcc"))     // false
```

---

Other one is more "natural". Two strings are anagrams if they have *the same count of each character*.
So you make two `Map[Char, Int]` and compare them:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

def areAnagram(str1: String, str2: String): Boolean = {
  val map1 = mutable.Map.empty[Char, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
  val map2 = mutable.Map.empty[Char, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
  for (c <- str1) map1(c) += 1
  for (c <- str2) map2(c) += 1
  map1 == map2
}
```

There is also another version of second solution with `Array`s probably, if you know the chars are only ASCII ones.
Or some other clever algorithm, IDK.

---

**EDIT**: One recursive solution could be to remove *the first char of str1* from *str2*. The rests of both strings must be anagrams also.
E.g. for `("amina", "niama")` first you throw out an `a` from both, and you get `("mina", "nima")`. Those 2 strings **must also be anagrams**, by definition.

```
def areAnagram(str1: String, str2: String): Boolean = {

  if (str1.length != str2.length) false
  else if (str1.isEmpty) true // end recursion
  else {
    val (c, r1) = str1.splitAt(1)
    val r2 = str2.replaceFirst(c, "") // remove c
    areAnagram(r1, r2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For sure the sort and compare is the best solution but the problem is that I need to use the hint provided by the problem and it is important to use recursion.

Comment: @user12743563 I added a recursive solution also. :D

Answer (score 2):

When you calculate anagrams you can take advantage of property of **XOR** operation, which says, that if you xor two same numbers you'd get 0.

Since characters in strings are essentially just numbers, you could run xor over all characters of both strings and if result is 0, then these strings are anagrams.

You could iterate over both strings using loop, but if you want to use recursion, I would suggest, that you convert your string to lists of chars.

Lists allow efficient splitting between first element (head of list) and rest (tail of list). So solution would go like this:

1. Split list to head and tail for both lists of chars.
2. Run xor over characters extracted from heads of lists and previous result.
3. Pass tails of list and result of xoring to the next recursive call.

When we get to the end of lists, we just return **true** is case result of xoring is **0**.

Last optimalization we can do is short-curcuiting with **false** whenever strings with different lengths are passed (since they never could be anagrams anyway).

Final solution:

```
def anagram(a: String, b: String): Boolean = {

  //inner function doing recursion, annotation @tailrec makes sure function is tail-recursive
  @tailrec
  def go(a: List[Char], b: List[Char], acc: Int): Boolean = { //using additional parameter acc, allows us to use tail-recursion, which is safe for stack
    (a, b) match {
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => //operator :: splits list to head and tail
        go(xs, ys, acc ^ x ^ y) //because we changed string to lists of chars, we can now efficiently access heads (first elements) of lists
      //we get first characters of both lists, then call recursively go passing tails of lists and result of xoring accumulator with both characters
      case _ => acc == 0 //if result of xoring whole strings is 0, then both strings are anagrams
    }
  }

  if (a.length != b.length) { //we already know strings can't be anagrams, because they've got different size
    false
  } else {
    go(a.toList, b.toList, 0)
  }
}

anagram("twelveplusone", "elevenplustwo") //true
anagram("amina", "minia") //false
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: Don't over-think it.

```
def anagram(a: String, b: String): Boolean =
  if (a.isEmpty) b.isEmpty
  else b.contains(a(0)) && anagram(a.tail, b diff a(0).toString)
```